# How to write a code to convert text into a number?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

The database I'm working on has a field in one table as a text whereas the other table has the field in a number format. I cannot change the field format at all in the database. Therefore I need to know how to convert the field from text to number before linking (or join)  the tables to pull the data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblCoachingDB.ID, tblCoachingDB.SourceId, tblCoachingDBSource.ID
FROM tblCoachingDB, tblCoachingDBSource
WHERE (((tblCoachingDB.SourceId)="12"));
```

The tblCoachingDB.SourceID is a TEXT whereas the tblCoachingDBSource.ID is a NUMBER

Comment: I cannot change the table design at all :S Hence asking for coding.

Comment: Ok I cannot even add the functions into the database - the developer long gone from the company I work for literally locked the database down from any modifications needing to be made to it. We are in the process of creating a new web database for it though. In the meantime, can you code the example of the CStr() so I have a better idea how to? Thank you :)

Comment: Looking at this link https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

Comment: Is Autonumber the same as Number?

Comment: For an example using `CStr()` in a query, paste this one into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer, and run it: `SELECT CStr(12) AS number_to_string`

Comment: Autonumber is a specialized case of Access' Long Integer numeric datatype.  So, yes it's a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CStr()` to cast a number as text and `JOIN` that to another text field.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblCoachingDB.ID,
    tblCoachingDB.SourceId,
    tblCoachingDBSource.ID
FROM
    tblCoachingDB INNER JOIN tblCoachingDBSource
    ON tblCoachingDB.SourceId = CStr(tblCoachingDBSource.ID)
WHERE tblCoachingDB.SourceId='12';
```

Actually I would leave out the `WHERE` clause until after you confirm the `JOIN` works properly.

You originally asked to `JOIN` by converting the text field to number.  I first suggested text instead because I recall Access was less likely to object.  But my memory about that is shaky, and if you want numeric for both sides of the `JOIN`, see which of these (if any) works best for you:

```sql
ON Int(tblCoachingDB.SourceId) = tblCoachingDBSource.ID
ON CLng(tblCoachingDB.SourceId) = tblCoachingDBSource.ID
ON Val(tblCoachingDB.SourceId) = tblCoachingDBSource.ID
```

Note I offered this suggestion only because you told us you are not permitted to alter your *tblCoachingDB* table's design to make *SourceId* numeric instead of text datatype.  Since you can't make that change, you will have to live with the run-time performance impact of converting the datatype of a `JOIN` field.  That is *not* a good thing, but I don't know how bad it will be.  Good luck.

Comment: So that query performance was OK?  I was really afraid it might run slower than a 3 legged pig.  :-)

Comment: Actually yes it was :) Validated the database and the return speed was fine!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all values in tblCoachingDB.SourceID are numbers, you could create a query, selecting all fields from tblCoachingDB EXCEPT SourceID. Then add a new field to the query SourceID: `clng(tblCoachingDB.SourceID)`

You would then use the query instead of tblCoachingDB anywhere you needed to make the join. A second alternative would be to create a query for tblCoachingDBSource and using SourceID: `cstr(tblCoaching.SourceID)` A third alternative would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCoachingDB, tblCoachingDBSource 
WHERE (clng(tblCoachingDB.SourceId)=tblCoachingDBSource.ID 
AND ((tblCoachingDB.SourceId)="12"));
```

Comment: This also works as well :) Thank you Newd! I am learning and loving it!

Comment: It was AVG, I just edited it to make it look prettier haha.  Don't forget to throw him an upvote too.

Comment: Yours and HansUP both returned the same results :)